# Change Input-Group-Addon Color when :focus on input? With Pure CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way you can change the input-group-addon icon color when focusing on the input form with pure CSS and no jQuery / Javascript? I've only found ways that use jQuery, was just wondering if it's possible to do with just CSS. If so, what CSS do I use? I've tried:

```
.form-control input:focus + .input-group-addon {
    color: #4183D7;
}
```

That doesn't work. What can I try?

Comment: you are using textbox before addon or after addon?

Comment: you can try this js for create such kind of css. `https://github.com/Idered/cssParentSelector`

Comment: @chiragsatapara before

Comment: @chiragsatapara the whole idea is to not use any js, just pure css

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Your email" class="form-control">
<span class="input-group-addon">@</span>

.form-control:focus + .input-group-addon {
    color: #4183D7;
}
```

this should work.